# UINavigationController swipeGesture in UISwipeView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, gesture

I have a `UINavigationController` to navigate through my app. One `UIViewController` contains only an `UIScrollView`. Now the iOS7 back-gesture of the `UINavigationController` doesn't work, because of the scrollview pan gestures.

How can I solve this so that I can use the `UINavigationController` back gesture?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem -> add in `viewDidLoad:`

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```